# When is the closed unit ball $B^*$ in the dual space strictly convex?

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm finding the conditions (on the primal normed space $X$ or on the closed unit ball $B$ of $X$) to ensure that the closed unit ball $B^*$ in the dual space $X^*$ is strictly convex. 
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit ball $B^*$ of dual space $X^*$ is strictly convex iff each  functional defined on subspace of $X$ have unique extension to the whole $X$.

If a functional $f$ has two Hahn-Banach extensions $g$ and $h$ then $(g+h)/2$ is also a Hahn-Banach extension, so $X^*$ isn't strictly convex. The other direction is due to Foguel, [see here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1958-009-02/S0002-9939-1958-0093696-3/home.html).